# Is opencv disparity map of real time stationary image meant to change?

Tags: opencv, disparity-mapping

Is a disparity map generated in OpenCV from two live camera feeds of a stationary scene meant to change over time???  (I assumed not but I am getting a changing disparity image.)

Comment: The disparity image generated by OpenCV is not quite accurate and is  affected by enviroment. So it may change even in a stationary scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the successive images from each camera are **exactly** the same (which is highly unlikely), the disparity image should change slightly.